# In Ember how to delete object from ArrayController

Tags: arrays, ember.js

I am doing the following but I m not able to retrieve the `this` obj from the context in methods `searchAgain` and `removeUser`. This is the example I am taking from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html

```
     <div id="recent">
            <h3>Recent Users</h3>
            <ol>
                {{#each App.recentUsersController.reverse}}
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="view again" {{action "searchAgain" target="App.recentUsersController"}}>{{this}}</a> - 
                        <a href="#" title="remove" {{action "removeUser" target="App.recentUsersController"}}>X</a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ol>
        </div>


   App.recentUsersController = Em.ArrayController.create({
content: [],
addUser: function(name) {
    if ( this.contains(name) ) this.removeObject(name);
    this.pushObject(name);
},
removeUser: function(view){
    alert(view.context);
    this.removeObject(view.context);
},
searchAgain: function(view){
    alert(view.context);
    App.tweetsController.set('username', view.context);
    App.tweetsController.loadTweets();
},
reverse: function(){
    return this.toArray().reverse();
}.property('@each')
```

});

The `view.context` inside `SearchAgain` and `removeUser` gives me undefined. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution; I hope this help others too:

- the methods of the `recentUsersController` actually receive an event, not a view (and I believe that's a mistake in the article)
- the `{{each}}` mustache should read `{{#each user in App.recentUsersController.reverse}}`, in order to declare an identifier for the object you are looping through
- while looping through the`recentUsers`, such identifier should be added inside the `{{action}}` mustache (e.g. `{{action "removeUser" "user" target="App.recentUsersController"}}`)